# Amazon SES certificate error no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

today I'm getting this error all of a sudden. Anyone else getting this and if so, where's this coming from?

---

PHP User Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): 51 SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'email.us-
west-2.amazonaws.com'

Comment: You have a issue with your certificate. Check if your configurations are correct and the certificate is still valid.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte How can I do this? Very hard to navigate Amazon SES to find this setting.